# jscrollpane margin bottom not working

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have the following for the CSS of jscrollpane:

```
.jspContainer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;  /*does not work*/
    border:0px solid red;
}
```

The top margin works but I don't get any margin at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the generated HTML after jScrollPane has run (using Firebug or your browser's web inspector) then you'll see that the `jspContainer` sits inside your original element (which has `overflow: hidden`). This is why the bottom margin doesn't do anything...

You could instead set the margin bottom on `jspScrollable` (a class that is added to your original element when it is made scrollable). Although you're not clear about where you would like the margin to appear?